# Recurrence $a_{n}=a_{\lfloor 2n/3\rfloor}+a_{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I am considering the sequence
$$a_n=a_{\lfloor 2n/3\rfloor}+a_{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}$$
with $a_0=1$, and I would like to calculate the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$$
I have seen [this famous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487957/how-prove-this-nice-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fraca-nn-frac12-lo) and its answer, but since the recurrence in this question has only two terms on the RHS instead of three, I was wondering if there is a more elementary solution that does not use specialized knowledge like renewal theory.

I have not made much progress; all I have managed to prove so far is that the sequence contains runs of arbitrarily long length, and this is probably not relevant to the desired limit.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/632559/572204)

Comment: Numerical data is consistent with the possibility that $a(n)/n$ is well approximated (as $n$ grows) by $f\big(\frac{\log n}{\log 3}\big)$ for some function $f$ of period $1$—that is, that $a(n)/n$ has some underlying fractal structure. If so, the limit would not exist. (It's also possible, though, that the quotient is more like $\alpha+\varepsilon(n)f\big(\frac{\log n}{\log 3}\big)$ for some function $\varepsilon(n)$ tending to $0$ and some constant $\alpha$ a bit less than $1.2$. But the running averages are also oscillating quite a bit.)

Comment: https://oeis.org/A163867, and yes, the graph is ugly indeed.

Comment: @GregMartin Numerical data may not seem convergent, but theoretically, the sequence is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $a_n/n$ is convergent.

We adapt the idea given in this paper [A master theorem for discrete divide and conquer recurrences](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.5555/2133036.2133064?download=true) by Michael Drmota, Wojciech  Szpankowski.

The general theorem and proof are given in the paper, so I will focus on this specific sequence in this posting.

Two main theorems are

**Theorem 1 (Landau)**

> Let $F(s)=\sum a_n n^{-s}$ be a Dirichlet series with a finite abscissa of convergence $\sigma_c$. If $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n$ then the point $\sigma_c$ is a singularity of the function $F(s)$.

Note that if $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n$ then $\sigma_c=\sigma_a$.

**Theorem 2 (Wiener-Ikehara)**

> Let $F(s)=\sum a_n n^{-s}$ with $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n$. Suppose $F(s)$ converges for $\sigma>1$ and $F(s)-c/(s-1)$ extends to a continuous function in the closed half-plane $\sigma \geq 1$. Then
> $$
> \sum_{n\leq x}a_n=cx+o(x).
> $$

Both theorems are in "Multiplicative Number Theory I. Classical Theory, by Montgomery & Vaughan". They are Theorem 1.7 and Corollary 8.8 in the book.

**Solution to the problem**

Let $b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$, we have $b_1=1$ and
$$
b_n= {\bf 1}_{3|n} b_{2n/3} + {\bf 1}_{n\equiv 2(3)} b_{(2n-1)/3} + {\bf 1}_{3|n} b_{n/3} \text{ if } n>1. \ (1)
$$

By induction, we have $0\leq b_n\leq n$ for all $n$. Thus, the Dirichlet series $F(s)=\sum b_n n^{-s}$ has a finite abscissa of absolute convergence $\sigma_a$.

By (1), we have for $\sigma>\sigma_a$,
$$
\sum b_n n^{-s} = 1+\sum_{3|n} b_{2n/3} n^{-s} + \sum_k b_{2k-1} (3k-1)^{-s} + \sum_{3|n} b_{n/3} n^{-s}. 
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
(1-3^{-s})& \sum b_n n^{-s} = 1 + \sum_k b_{2k} (3k)^{-s} + \sum_k b_{2k-1} (3k-1)^{-s}\\
&=1+(3/2)^{-s} \left( \sum_k b_{2k} (2k)^{-s} + \sum_k b_{2k-1} (2k-\frac23)^{-s} \right).
\end{align}
$$
The last sum can be written as
$$
\sum_k b_{2k-1}(2k-1)^{-s} + \sum_k b_{2k-1}\left((2k-\frac23)^{-s}-(2k-1)^{-s}\right).
$$
Then we have
$$
\left(1-3^{-s}-(\frac32)^{-s}\right) \sum b_n n^{-s} $$
$$= 1+ (\frac32)^{-s} \sum_k b_{2k-1} \left((2k-\frac23)^{-s}-(2k-1)^{-s}\right).  \ \ (2)
$$
By ML-inequality,
$$\left|(2k-\frac23)^{-s}-(2k-1)^{-s}\right|$$
$$=\left|\int_{2k-1}^{2k-\frac23} (-s)x^{-s-1} dx\right|=O(|s|k^{-\sigma-1})$$
with an absolute implied O-constant.

Thus, the RHS of (2) defines an analytic function on $\sigma>\sigma_a-1$. On the LHS of (2), $1-3^{-s}-(3/2)^{-s}$ has a unique real zero at $s=1$ which is simple, and $\sum b_n n^{-s}$ is analytic on $\sigma>\sigma_a$ with singularity at $\sigma_a$ by Landau's theorem. Hence, the singularity at $\sigma_a$ must be removable. This implies $\sigma_a = 1$. Also, $1-3^{-s}-(3/2)^{-s}$ does not have complex zero $1+it$ with $t\neq 0$.

Thus, we obtain the expression
$$
F(s)=\frac{1+ (\frac32)^{-s} \sum_k b_{2k-1} \left((2k-\frac23)^{-s}-(2k-1)^{-s}\right)}{1-3^{-s}-(\frac32)^{-s}}. \ \ (3)
$$
Moreover, $F(s)-c/(s-1)$ extends to a continuous function on $\sigma\geq 1$ where $c$ is
$$
c=\frac{3+2\sum_k b_{2k-1} \left( (2k-\frac23)^{-1}-(2k-1)^{-1}\right)}{\log\frac{27}4}.
$$

By Wiener-Ikehara's theorem, we obtain
$$
\sum_{n\leq x} b_n \sim cx. 
$$
For the original problem, we have
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_n}n=\frac{3+2\sum_k b_{2k-1} \left( (2k-\frac23)^{-1}-(2k-1)^{-1}\right)}{\log\frac{27}4}.
$$

**Remark.**
The convergence may be very slow and difficult to observe. However, the convergence is mainly due to the following
$$\frac{\log(2/3)}{\log(1/3)} \notin \mathbb{Q}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Akra-Bazzi theorem (see for instance Leighton ["Notes on Better Master Theorems for Divide-and-Conquer Recurrences"](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/doc_view/pid/513611099c8ba4c5b8b878af143641175fe351b0); sorry, no "formal" reference available).

Given the recurrence $T(z) = g(z) + \sum_{1 \le k \le n} a_k T(b_k z + h_k(z))$
for $z \le z_0$, with $a_k, b_k$ constants, $a_k > 0$ and $0 < b_k < 1$, if $\lvert h_k(z) \rvert = O(z/\log^2 z)$ and $g(z) = O(z^c)$ for some $c$.
Define $p$ as the unique solution to $\sum_{1 \le k \le n} a_k b_k^p = 1$, then the solution to the recurrence satisfies:

$\begin{align*}
  T(z)
    &= \Theta\left(
                z^p \left(
                       1 + \int_1^n \frac{g(u)}{u^{p + 1}} d u
                    \right)
             \right)
\end{align*}$

In this case the $h_k()$ are at most $1/2$, which satisfies the hypothesis, $g(n) = 0$ and $p = 1$, so we deduce $a_n = \Theta(n)$.

Comment: This is a mathematical wonder weapon! Very nice answer.

Comment: Found the reference at http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/spring04/handouts/akrabazzi.pdf