# floor function, algebra

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

a sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge0}$ is defined by $a_0=1$ and $$a_{n+1}=a_{{\lfloor}\frac{7n} 
{9}{\rfloor}}+a_{{\lfloor}\frac{n}{9}{\rfloor}}$$ for $n\ge0$.prove that there is an $n$ such that $a_n<\frac{n}{2001!}$

how do i approach this? we see that $a_1=2,a_3=a_4=3,a_5=a_6=a_7=4,a_8=a_9=5$.Is there any pattern coming out?Does induction work here?

Comment: Unclear to me whether the answer of Henry Lee is either valid, or can be made valid. Anyway, for an alternative, less elegant approach, for  $~k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},~$  let  f(k)  denote the largest positive integer  n  such that  $~a_n=k.~$  Then, manually compute  f(5),f(6),⋯,f(10).  Then using these computations as data, look for a pattern in the data. Then, use this perceived pattern to formulate a hypothesis about the computation of  f(k)  as a function of  k. ...see next comment

Comment: Then, try to prove this hypothesis, perhaps through induction. Then, once this hypothesis is proven, apply the hypothesis to the posted question. For what it's worth, it is unclear to me whether the approach that I have outlined will conquer the problem. However, this would automatically be my first try.

Comment: sir @MartinR $a_4=a_{{\lfloor}\frac{21}{9}{\rfloor}}+a_{{\lfloor}\frac{3}{9}{\rfloor}}=a_2+a_0=2+1=3$

Comment: @mikedennes: You are right, my fault, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

The following is inspired by

- “A Pseudo-Fibonacci Limit” in Luthar, R. S., Julio Castineira, Barry Powell, Daniel A. Rawsthorne, H. L. Krall, J. C. Binz, William Wernick, et al. “Problems.” Mathematics Magazine 57, no. 1 (1984): 41–50. https://doi.org/10.2307/2690297.

where the similar problem

> Set $a_0 = 1$ and for $n \ge 1$, $a_n = a_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} + a_{\lfloor n/3 \rfloor}$. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n/n$.

is solved (also mentioned in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/632559/42969)).

---

The idea is to prove that the sequence satisfies
$$ \tag{$*$}
 a_n  \le C n^r
$$
for all $n \ge 1$, with some suitably chosen $r \in (0, 1)$ and some $C > 0$. First, the exponent $r$ is chosen such that
$$
 \left( \frac{7}{9}\right)^r + \left( \frac{1}{9}\right)^r < 1 \, ,
$$
for example $\boxed{r = 0.8}$. Next, the factor $C$ is chosen $(*)$ holds for $1 \le n \le 9$, for example $\boxed{C = 2}$. Finally, $(*)$ is proven for all $n \ge 1$ with induction.

It follows from $(*)$  that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n} = 0 \, ,
$$
so that $a_n / n < 1/2001!$ eventually.

Comment: sir is there any way to find a bound or expression for $n$?

Comment: @mikedennes: You need $2n^{0.8} < n/2001!$ or $2\cdot 2001! < n^{0.2}$, i.e. $n > (2 \cdot 2001!)^5$.

Comment: sir @MartinR sorry to bother u again-what purpose does this assumption serve -"exponent r
 is chosen such that"-$$
 \left( \frac{7}{9}\right)^r + \left( \frac{1}{9}\right)^r < 1 \, ,
$$

Comment: @mikedennes: That is needed when you prove with induction that (*) holds for all $n$.

Answer (score -1):

Proof by contradiction

Assume:
$$\forall n\exists a_n\ge\frac{n}{2001!}$$
Consider:
$$a_{2001!}\ge\frac{2001!}{2001!}=1$$
now using the recurrance relation:
$$a_{2001!+9}=a_{\left\lfloor\frac{7(2001!+9)}{9}\right\rfloor}+a_{\left\lfloor\frac{2001!+9}{9}\right\rfloor}$$
$$a_{2001!+9}=a_{\left\lfloor\frac{7\times2001!}{9}+\frac{7\times9}{9}\right\rfloor}+a_{\left\lfloor\frac{2001!}{9}+\frac99\right\rfloor}$$
Now notice that $\frac{7\times2001!}{9}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\frac{7\times9}{9}=7$ so the first term's floor bracket contains an integer. Similarly, $\left(\frac{2001!}{9}+1\right)\in\mathbb{Z}$. As a result $a_{2001!+9}\ge1+1=2$. Repeating this for any $a_{2001!+9k}$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ yields the same inequality. This implies: $\forall n>2001!,a_n\ge2$.

Now, comparing $a_{2\times2001!}\ge2$ to $\frac{2\times2001!}{2001!}=2$ shows a contradiction as we assumed:
$$a_n\ge\frac{n}{2001!}\forall n$$
But we have shown that:
$$a_{2\times2001!}<\frac{2\times2001!}{2001!}=2$$
Hence our initial assumption must be false:
$$\therefore\exists n\,\,s.t.\,\,a_n<\frac{n}{2001!}$$
And that completes the proof

---

EDIT:

Let $b_n = \frac{a_n}{n}$.

Consider $b_{2001!}$. By the recurrence relation:
$$b_{2001!} = \frac{a_{2001!}}{2001!} \geq \frac{1}{2001!}$$
Now, let's compute $b_{2001! + 9}$:
$$b_{2001! + 9} = \frac{a_{2001! + 9}}{2001! + 9}$$
Notice that $b_{2001! + 9}$ depends only on $b_n$ for $n$ in the range $[2001!, 2001!+9]$. Since there are 10 terms in this range, by the Pigeonhole Principle, at least one of these terms must be less than or equal to the average:
$\frac{b_{2001!} + b_{2001! + 1} + \ldots + b_{2001! + 9}}{10}$
Therefore, there exists $k$ such that $b_{2001! + k} \leq \frac{b_{2001!} + b_{2001! + 1} + \ldots + b_{2001! + 9}}{10}$.
Since $b_{2001!} \geq \frac{1}{2001!}$, we have:
$\frac{b_{2001!} + b_{2001! + 1} + \ldots + b_{2001! + 9}}{10} \geq \frac{1}{2001!}$
Combining the above inequalities, we get:
$b_{2001! + k} \leq \frac{1}{2001!}$
This implies:
$a_{2001! + k} \leq \frac{2001! + k}{2001!} = 1 + \frac{k}{2001!}$
Finally, since $k \geq 0$, we have:
$a_{2001! + k} < 1 + \frac{1}{2001!} \leq \frac{1}{2001!}$
This completes the proof, demonstrating that there exists an $n$ (specifically, $n = 2001! + k$) such that $a_n < \frac{n}{2001!}$.

Comment: @MartinR I didn't want to delete the first proof as I'd only just posted it but I think I made an error there and wasn't sure so just posted the second proof to slot in

Comment: $a_{2001! + 9}$ depends on $a_{2001!/9 + 1}$, therefore I do not understand your argument starting at “Notice that $b_{2001! + 9}$ depends only on ...”

Comment: $\forall n\exists a_n\ge\frac{n}{2001!}$ makes no sense

Comment: @jjagmath true, but his intent is the assertion (which he then tries to prove is false) that $~\forall ~n, ~a_n \geq \dfrac{n}{2001!}.$